# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10e2d62f0>

Tags: mysql, django, macos, terminal

This is my first question. I'll try to get it right.

After having no problems running Django on my dev environment (on macOS 10.14.6) for over a year, I tried to start the server today and got this message:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10e2d62f0>
```

With this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 199, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 52, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 119, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 316, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 115, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mtd83/_Dev/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

The problem probably has to do with some edits I made yesterday. I was trying to update Homebrew and I got a message that I had to change ownership and permissions to three files. Unfortunately I didn't take notes on what they were. It involed `chown` with the `-R` option.

Also, if it's any help, I've alway had to use sudo before manage.py runserver 80.

Sorry, I know this is pretty vague. Any help would be really appreciated.